# Which of the following is not a Network Layer protocol in TCP/IP model?

Tags: networking, network-programming

Which of the following is not a Network Layer protocol in TCP/IP model?

A) ICMP
B) IGMP
C) IP
D) SNTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNTP, should be the answer, as all others are protocols working on the network layer, i.e. internet layer of the TCP/IP stack whereas, SNTP is an application layer protocol that helps in synchronizing clocks over the network.

You can read more about these protocols here:

- [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)
- [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol)
- [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol)
- [SNTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)

Comment: thank you sir for answering my question. Thanks again.